# Scrape with bs4 two values for one variable, how can i use just one?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the price of different amazon pages. The problem is that when the product is "amazon choice" the price is in different "div", so... how can i check if the price is in one tag or another and then, save that value as price. Then give to that value price a int format, ready to be save to one cell on xlsx file. I have this code without error, but i cant delete the option None of the print result. If i try replace gimme error, if i use get_text gimme error. So... i dont know what else to do. Im in blank.

```
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com.mx/dp/B07MJP47M5'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
scrape = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')

price_1 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
if price_1 != None:
    price_1 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()


price_2 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_saleprice')
if price_2 != None:
    price_2 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_saleprice').get_text()



price = (price_1, price_2)
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solver this problem.

```
URL = 'https://www.amazon.com.mx/dp/B07T514NTL'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
scrape = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# se extrae el precio y se le da formato, se quita la coma, y las decimales y el simbolo

price_1 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_ourprice')
if price_1 is None:
    price_1 = scrape.find(id='priceblock_saleprice')

price_4 = price_1.get_text()

verted_price = price_4[1:10]
onverted_price = verted_price.replace(',','')
sep = '.'
converted_price = onverted_price.split(sep, 1)[0]

print(converted_price)
```